# How to automate curl tests with karate?

Tags: karate

We used karate framework to test access token generation. 
Can we use it to automate our tests concerning authentication via cURL? can smbody give tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the dev of Karate and would like to understand what exactly you are trying to do. Do you mean just being able to experiment and explore the API ? Please see if the [Karate UI](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI) fits your needs or suggest improvements.

If you have automated tests in the form of Karate scripts, why would you need cURL any more ?  Maybe you want a converter for Karate into cURL, you can submit a feature request to build it into the Karate UI.

EDIT - also see: [Is possible to execute curl in Karate tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64352517/143475)

Comment: Do we have this feature available? curl to karate converter?

Comment: only in the vs code plugin: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1176570588896227328