# Is possible to execute curl in Karate tests?

Tags: karate

I need to run some test that use a NTLM proxy.
Due to Karate doesn´t support NTLM proxy, I think that if karate can "execute" a curl command like below, I will get kate working with NTLM:

```
curl -X GET 'https://someaddress.com/cats?Status=completed' -u siteuser:sitepasswd    --proxy-ntlm --proxy-user ckuser:ckpasswd --proxy internal-ntlm-proxy:8080 -s
```

Anyone knows if I can call a curl command in Karate? (instead of the internal http request that Karate use when call Given... Path...)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Karate has very good CLI support, if `curl` is present on your OS, it can be done.  See this answer for details, available in 0.9.6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/62911366/143475

In your case, try first with [`karate.exec()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-exec)

```
* def result = karate.exec("curl -X GET 'https://someaddress.com/cats?Status=completed' -u siteuser:sitepasswd    --proxy-ntlm --proxy-user ckuser:ckpasswd --proxy internal-ntlm-proxy:8080 -s")
```

And `result` will contain the console text. Note that there are [regex helpers](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/extract.feature) to make scraping values out easier, for e.g.:

```
* def token = karate.extract(result, 'some(pattern).+', 1)
```

For more tips on how to parameterize tests to be dynamic and use variables, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352676/143475

Comment: @jsturnio and thank you ! NTLM has been requested before a few times and `curl` never occured to me, so I've edited an old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49878436/143475 - do report back once you get this to work !