# How to save downloaded ZIP file from the Endpoint with KARATE

Tags: maven, curl, karate

I'm pretty new in karate so, I need your help.
I have .feature file. We have API which should return .zip file with commits data

```
    Given path EndpointUrl + 'request-commit/{param1}/{param2}'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    And def responsebytes = responsebytes
```

Overall scrip works fine because in Content-disposition i do see attachment ".zip" file

In case when I use

```
curl -k link --request GET -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'client_id: 12344' -H 'accept: application/json' -O -J
```

from remote_host I can download .zip file

But how to get zip into a local dir after the script execution?
How to use the proper flags -O and -J from curl call in karate?
Could you please help me to resolve this question?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should save a file to `target/foo.zip`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475

```
* karate.write(responseBytes, 'foo.zip')
```

Also you may find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352676/143475