# Broken pipe (Write failed) when testing > max allowed Content-Length

Tags: karate

I am trying to write a test which validates my server rejects requests larger than 1MB:

```
Scenario: large requests are rejected
    Given url 'https://my.server.com/anything'
    And request "x".repeat(1048577)
    When method post
    Then status 413
```

This test fails with an `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Broken pipe (Write failed)` exception because the server reads the `Content-Length` header and immediately rejects the request / responds with a 413 before reading the payload.

I verified the server behavior via cURL:

```
$> printf 'x%.0s' {1..1048577} | curl -i --data @- https://my.server.com/anything
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
```

Is it possible to test this feature using Karate?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly can be a case which Karate is not designed for. You may not have full control over some "special" headers like the `Content-Length` - and we are limited by the underlying Apache HTTP client.

I'm not sure if the upcoming 1.0 series will support this and allow you to over-write the `Content-Length` header: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

But you are welcome to investigate and submit a PR if needed.

As a workaround, you can use cURL from Karate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352676/143475

And also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73230200/143475