# Using cURL for API automation in Karate

Tags: api, testing, curl, karate

I'm new to Karate

I'm automating an API test where I need to upload a large file >50MB
When I do so with Karate I get an error "Broken Pipe" and according to this question
[Broken pipe (Write failed) when testing > max allowed Content-Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250166/broken-pipe-write-failed-when-testing-max-allowed-content-length) I could use "cURL" for this request.

It's working fine as follows (with hardcoded data):

```
* def result = karate.exec('curl -L -X POST "URL" -H "Authorization: Bearer MYTOKEN" -F "file=@"PATH""')
```

However, I'm having issues with the syntax when passing variables
I need to pass the URL, token, and path as variables and not hardcoded text since I will be reusing this test for multiple landscapes.

How would I go about it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the Karate syntax as very close to JavaScript. So, string concatenation works. For example:

```
* def myUrl = 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* def result = karate.exec('curl ' + myUrl)
```

And a nice thing is that JavaScript [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) work:

```
* def myUrl = 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* def result = karate.exec(`curl ${myUrl}`)
```

Also note that the `karate.exec()` API takes an array of command-line arguments. This can make some things easier like not having to put quotes around arguments with white-space included etc.

```
* def myUrl = 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* def result = karate.exec({ args: [ 'curl', myUrl ] })
```

You can build the arguments array as a second step for convenience:

```
* def myUrl = 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* def args = ['curl']
* args.push(myUrl)
* def result = karate.exec({ args: args })
```

Note that conditional logic and even an `if` statement is possible in Karate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62911366/143475

Comment: Thank you! this worked. 
Another question, for this API I need to upload a zip file whose path is in the project. 
If I just read the file it passes the file as bytes instead of a zip. So I was able to get around it by doing this 
* def responseBytes = karate.read("file:classpath:com/PATH/file.zip) 
    * def file = karate.write(responseBytes, 'temp-file.zip')
    * def result = karate.exec(`curl -L -X POST ${myUrl} \-H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" \-F dta=@${file}`)  is there a more efficient/elegant way to do this?  Thanks,

Comment: @thecybergirl wow, I think you figured it out perfectly. what you can do is roll your own JS function, maybe call it in the `Background` and then make this a one-liner: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#commonly-needed-utilities