# How to use custom path in karate feature file?

Tags: pom.xml, karate, web-api-testing

In the karate feature file,  classpath is  - "scr/test/java"

But instead, the detailed  "classpath:examples/resources/module1/sub_module/test.json" path, Is there any other way that hides the detailed path? like

Here, My expectation is Instead of

- def file1 = read(classpath:examples/resources/module1/sub_module/test.json)

I want to use

- def file1 = read(customclasspath:test.json) or similar to this which can hide the full path details of any file in the feature file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a variable?

```
* def myPath = 'classpath:foo/bar/'
```

And then later:

```
* def file1 = read(myPath + 'test.json')
```

More hints on variable substitution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73230200/143475