# karate.exec(['python3', 'filename.py', 'arg']) is ignoring the argument

Tags: python-3.x, karate

`karate.exec(['python3', 'filename.py', 'arg'])` is ignoring the argument

I have a secretkey declared in karate-config.js file and use the variable in all my feature files, but that is not accessible in filename.py(which is obvious).
So, I am using

```
karate.exec(['python3', 'filename.py', secretkey])
```

where secretkey is an argument for a function in filename.py.
The problem here is karate is ignoring the argument i.e., secretkey. I am trying to access it in filename.py as `sys.argv[1]`
The result is `IndexError: list index out of range`; because karate is ignoring the argument
`DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [python3, Ingest-snapshot.py]`

Comment: that sounds like a bug, so please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also refer other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73230200/143475

Comment: My mistake, I was calling karate.exec('python3 filename.py') in Background. I think I should delete this question, It will be misleading. There is no issue with Karate.

Comment: glad you sorted it out, I'll mark as duplicate so it can be closed

Comment: Great, Thanks for the quick response though.