# I need to validate request time out in karate api testing

Tags: api, testing, automation, karate, request-timed-out

We ar doing api testing using karate and i want to provide less time out and validate 408 error

Tried * configure requestTimeout=100

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work. If it doesn't you can assume this is not supported by Karate. In my experience, these kinds of tests are not worth automating. Also look at the option of using `cURL` directly: [Using cURL for API automation in Karate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73227903/143475)

```
* configure readTimeout = 100
* url someUrl
* method get
* status 408
```