How to use karate.exec to issue a curl command?
I am having a curl command . I want to use karate.exec function and use curl utility to issue a request and parse the response.
The following is my curl command
curl   --header "router-destination-service-name: localService" --header "router-destination-service-namespace: local"  -X GET "localhost:9876/echo1?zzz=123&aaa=123&yyy=123&bbb=123&xxx=123&ccc=123&www=123"

The output of the curl command is
{
  "serverHostname": "localService",
  "reqeustMethod": "GET",
  "requestHeaders": {
    "x-http2-scheme": [
      "http"
    ],
    "host": [
      "172.22.0.2:8090"
    ],
    "user-agent": [
      "Vert.x-WebClient/4.4.4",
      "curl/7.29.0"
    ],
    "accept": [
      "*/*"
    ],
    "x-request-id": [
      "ca7f8b95-93ce-4a64-faa8-6207cb65015d"
    ],
    "x-http2-stream-id": [
      "3"
    ],
    "x-http2-stream-weight": [
      "16"
    ],
    "content-length": [
      "0"
    ]
  },
  "requestUri": "/echo1?zzz=123&aaa=123&yyy=123&bbb=123&xxx=123&ccc=123&www=123",
  "requestParams": {
    "zzz": [
      "123"
    ],
    "aaa": [
      "123"
    ],
    "yyy": [
      "123"
    ],
    "bbb": [
      "123"
    ],
    "xxx": [
      "123"
    ],
    "ccc": [
      "123"
    ],
    "www": [
      "123"
    ]
  },
  "requestBody": "BODY NOT SET"
}

please suggest me  an example karate test , where I can issue a curl request using karate.exec() and then have the response as an object. Then I want to extract a property from the response for example  requestUri or reqeustMethod and perform an assertion. I strictly want to use karate.exec(command). I dont want the normal GIVEN WHEN THEN scenarios
thank you

please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352517/is-possible-to-execute-curl-in-karate-tests

please provide me  a complete example . i have also seen that link but didnt work .

@StarbucksAdmin did you read all the links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352676/143475 - if that doesn't help, there is nothing else, sorry
